# Coredump in fread when pointing to file in array

Tags: c, fread, coredump

Recently started working with pointers and have created a little script that is supposed to stich together some textfiles.

However when i try to call fputs i get a coredump/segmentation error. I suspect it is because of the way that the file pointer is saved. I find the files saves it in an array and tries to retrieve it later on.

the FILE pointer is saved in a struct. Does somebody instantly spot my fault? i would be very grateful!

The struct:

```
typedef struct{
int listSize;
int listCapacity;
FILE *fileStream;
}FileList;
```

Creating the struct

```
FileList fileList;
fileList.listSize=0;
fileList.listCapacity=1;
fileList.fileStream=calloc(fileList.listCapacity,sizeof(FILE));
```

and then i add the struct to the array by calling

```
void addFile(FileList* list, FILE* file)
{
    list->fileStream[list->listSize]=*file;
}
```

However when i call

```
char* buffer[10];
size_t result=0;

result = fread(buffer,1,10,&fileList.fileStream[ii+currentGroupOffset]);
    fputs(*buffer,outPutFile);
```

it crashes, i tried to watch the value ii+currentGroupOffset making sure it doesnt go out the array bounds

any help at all appriciated! :)

Comment: What is `ii` and `currentGroupOffset` values at the time of the call? Your array has only one element, so both must be zero for this to work. How/when is `fopen` called?

Comment: Store `file`, not `*file`, then use `fileList.fileStream[...]` and not `&fileList.fileStream[...]`.

Comment: `ii` and `currentGroupOffset` is both 0 at the first time its called which also is the time the crash occurs. It is called inside a for loop iterating through the files in the array

Comment: Ooops, I overlooked that you have `FILE` array and not `FILE*` array, which is obviously wrong. Both answers below are perfectly right! And still, `FILE*` is returned by `fopen()`, do you ever call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't allocate and copy around `FILE` structures yourself - it's an opaque data type.  So, instead of creating an array of `FILE` structures, create an array of `FILE *` pointers:

```
typedef struct {
    int listSize;
    int listCapacity;
    FILE **fileStream;
} FileList;

FileList fileList;

fileList.listSize = 0;
fileList.listCapacity = 1;
fileList.fileStream = calloc(fileList.listCapacity, sizeof fileList.fileStream[0]);
```

then add a `FILE *` pointer to the array by copying the pointer value:

```
void addFile(FileList *list, FILE *file)
{
    list->fileStream[list->listSize] = file;
}
```

and use it like so:

```
char buffer[10];
size_t result = 0;

result = fread(buffer, 1, 10, fileList.fileStream[ii+currentGroupOffset]);
fwrite(buffer, 1, result, outPutFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want a dynamically allocated array of `FILE*` elements. You have:

```
FILE *fileStream;
```

That can either be treated as a `FILE` pointer, or an array of `FILE` elements. But not as an array of `FILE` pointers. For that, you need:

```
FILE **fileStream;
```

And allocating the array should be done with:

```
fileList.fileStream=calloc(fileList.listCapacity,sizeof(FILE*));
```

`FILE` is not a type you use directly. You always deal with pointers to it. You should treat it as an opaque type.

Also, I don't see where you actually open the files (using `fopen()`) anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Why

```
char * buffer[10];
```

It should be

```
char buffer[10];
```

Where is `list->listSize` incremented?

I don't understand what this is

```
 fileList.fileStream=calloc(fileList.listCapacity,sizeof(FILE));
```

`FILE *`s are initialized by calling `fopen` not by allocating memory